# How can we call Alloy from Java without opening the interface?

Tags: java, interface, alloy, sat

I am writing a program that needs to call Alloy on a model, and do something on the returned instance. The problem is that the Alloy interface is opened, every-time the Alloy command is called. I am wondering if there is anyway we can call Alloy from Java code without the interface being opened.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the examples of using the Alloy API that do not invoke the the Alloy GUI: http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/alloy-api-examples.html